# Site owner cannot open Site permissions page

Tags: 2013, permissions, site, site-settings

On SharePoint team site, one of site owners cannot access Site Permissions page.
When he tries to open that page he gets message bellow
[image]

Weird thing is, when he sends request to access that page and I get mail, I give him permissions (tried contribute, Full permissions) he again gets same message, *Let us know..*

Worth mentioning is that he can give permissions by opening item's Open menu and then putting names of users with whom he wants to share SP location.

I went to logs and saw the only error/warning I got was

```
Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|domain\username, ClaimsCount=37
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Site owner had Full permissions on site collection level, he was member of Owners group. On site level, inheritance was broken and all site collection groups were removed.
After we removed user from site collection owners group and gave him simple read permissions (we tried with contribute also, works) he managed to open site permissions and every other location on site he wasn't able to.

We read somewhere that there might get collision between permissions of a user if child site had same permissions as parent and than new groups got created and parent groups removed. So this might be the case at our problem, but luckily we solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was restoring site owner access to the hidden **Access Requests** list.  I do not know how permissions were lost in the first place.  While on the **Access requests and invitations** page I opened **Developer Tool** to obtain the list GUID.  I then entered the list GUID into the address bar and re-granted access to the site's Owners group.  Step-by-step instructions with screenshots are available at https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/restore-lost-permissions-to-access-requests-and-invitations-and-or-site-permissions/.

Answer (score 0):

Was the site restored recently?  If it was then rip that person out of site collection admin and then put him back.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/10f7b7cb-1493-4d7c-870c-efc90a109a7a/nonoauth-request-isauthenticatedtrue-useridentityname0w-claimscount36?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: no. site wasn't restored.

Comment: Still, try ripping that person out of site collection admin and then put him back.  Odds are low this will work, but it is a troubleshooting step, so it should be ruled out.